# android camera app is giving 0kb image

Tags: android

I have written following code to capture a image by using built in camera in mobile,but it is giving 0 kb image..plz help

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File sampleDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        try {
            pic = File.createTempFile("customr", ".jpg", sampleDir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("error", "sdcard access error");
            return;
        }

         // create a file to save the image
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, pic.getName()); // set the   image file name

        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

}
```